# How do you reference a second SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I reference a second server in SQL.

```
SELECT A.datasetid, 
       A.dsdate, 
       B.datasetid AS Expr1, 
       B.dsdate    AS Expr2 
FROM   we_ci_db.tblopportunitydatasets AS A 
       INNER JOIN we_ci_db.tblopportunitydatasets AS B 
               ON A.datasetid = B.datasetid
```

Assume that table 'B' is on a different server, what would the syntax be.  I've tried putting the server name before the schema, but it doesn't recognise it

Comment: Different Server, not different Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure a linked server.  Once that is configured, the linked server may be referenced as

```
server.database.schema.object
```

Comment: Not sure about the linked server, but I'd been trying server.schema.object    Then after Goat CO's message I tried server.database.schema.object and hey presto. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to create a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) by running the `addlinkedserver` stored procedure:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'SRVR002\ACCTG', 
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;
GO
```

After that, you can refer to the linked server with the syntax:

```
select *
from [SRVR002\ACCTG].[database name].[owner name].[table name]
```

[More Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, my mistake, don't need it for basic SELECT etc, but you do for INSERT INTO, which is what I need.  I've done the above code, but you can only see the default database and I get a Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Comment: @aSystemOverload - Ah, I'm not an expert in SQL Server so I probably can't help much more.  I'd check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and read up on permissions and authentication issues.